# Google static map not showing more than 5 pins

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I tried everything but whatever I do static Google map is now showing more than 5 pins.
My static map URL is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.508708883,16.439189110&zoom=7&size=640x320&key=MY_API_KEY&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-1.png?v=7|43.508708,16.439189&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-2.png?v=7|43.172360,16.441608&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-3.png?v=7|42.787800,17.345000&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-4.png?v=7|42.650600,18.091400&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-5.png?v=7|42.958300,17.134400&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-6.png?v=7|43.296700,17.017800&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-7.png?v=7|43.444400,16.688300&markers=icon:http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-8.png?v=7|43.508708,16.439189

It seems it is short enough because limit is 2048 characters. It has only 8 pins. There is only limit is markers if it has adress instead of latitude and longitude.

I lost few hours and whatever I do it is not showing pin 6 7 and 8.
Yes, they exist on server as you can see:
http://test2018.adriagate.com/images/pin-number-icon-8.png

Comment: **None** of the URLs you shared can be reached on my end. **All of them** return `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` Further to that I see 8 pins on the map you shared, just 3 of them have a different icon.

Comment: Can you explain me why you downvoted? URL is working, and yes 3 of them are different icon because as I sad google statc map only took first 5 images. That is why posted this question in the first place

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented behavior of Static Maps API.

Have a look at this page
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Markers

There is the following statement

> You can use **up to five unique custom icons** per request. This limitation does not mean that you are limited to only 5 marked locations on your map. Each unique icon may be used with more than one markers location on your map.

There was also feature request in Google issue tracker to allow more than 5 unique icons:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825584

However, Google marked this feature request as duplicated in favor of another feature request regarding KML layers in static maps:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817020

Feel free to star the feature request to express your interest.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.